# Как правильно отправлять aiohttp запрос ?[PYTHON]

Tags: python, aiohttp

```
start_time = time.time()
all_data = []

async def get_page_data(session,productid) -> str:
    url = f'https://www.binance.com/bapi/nft/v1/friendly/nft/nft-trade/product-detai'
    data = f'{"productId":{productid}}'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Referer': 'https://www.binance.com/ru/nft/goods/blindBox/detail?productId=7753917&isOpen=false&isProduct=1',
        'lang': 'ru',
        'x-ui-request-trace': 'be9c49b6-cdeb-4b0d-bde7-78da7249a281',
        'x-trace-id': 'be9c49b6-cdeb-4b0d-bde7-78da7249a281',
        'bnc-uuid': '0671fade-7ca0-4210-a195-218caedadc9a',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'device-info': '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',
        'clienttype': 'web',
        'fvideo-id': '31326ebb3230a7a8a513b58a202c87ecbd3508c9',
        'csrftoken': 'bd42c7189a2980b1a9e9a955c6bf2d1a',
        'Origin': 'https://www.binance.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'TE': 'trailers',
    }
    async with session.post(url,data=data,headers={'contenst-type': 'application/json',}) as resp:
        print(f'get url: {url}')
        respon = await resp.text()
        all_data.append(respon)

        return respon


async def load_site_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for productid in range(7753917,7753930):
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_page_data(session, productid))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(load_site_data())

end_time = time.time() - start_time
print(all_data)
```

Вылетает кучу ошибок

Код на request работает исправно(код ниже), но в чём проблема aiohttp?:

```
    import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.binance.com/ru/nft/goods/blindBox/detail?productId=7753917&isOpen=false&isProduct=1',
    'lang': 'ru',
    'x-ui-request-trace': 'be9c49b6-cdeb-4b0d-bde7-78da7249a281',
    'x-trace-id': 'be9c49b6-cdeb-4b0d-bde7-78da7249a281',
    'bnc-uuid': '0671fade-7ca0-4210-a195-218caedadc9a',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'device-info': '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',
    'clienttype': 'web',
    'fvideo-id': '31326ebb3230a7a8a513b58a202c87ecbd3508c9',
    'csrftoken': 'bd42c7189a2980b1a9e9a955c6bf2d1a',
    'Origin': 'https://www.binance.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'TE': 'trailers',
}

data = '{"productId":"7753917"}'

response = requests.post('https://www.binance.com/bapi/nft/v1/friendly/nft/nft-trade/product-detail', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: Какие именно ошибки вылетают?

Comment: @CrazyElf Дай свой telegram, заплачу за помощь.

Comment: Не, я в этом aiohttp не спец вообще, просто наводящие вопросы задаю, чтобы вам смогли тут помочь.

Comment: @CrazyElf Там 950 строк ошибок

Comment: Тогда вряд-ли вам тут кто-то поможет. Попробуйте сделать запрос на одну позицию для начала, а не на целый диапазон. Может ошибок будет меньше и что-то будет понятнее.

Comment: "Разделяй и властвуй". Попробуйте разбить ваш код на маленькие части, которые будут отвечать за какую-то ограниченную часть процесса. Попробуйте избавиться от какой-то функциональности, чтобы было проще найти ошибку, сделать минимальную версию.